# Ajax refreshing DB results every 5 seconds, but need to refresh only new content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using ajax to refresh my DB table results every 5 seconds how ever as the results in the table store date/time, I'm trying to figure out how I could load all current data for 20 "New" results in the cache and then load Only new results ever 5 seconds, rather than having the whole table refresh.

Here's my current code:

```html
     <script language="JavaScript"> 
   setInterval("updateContent();", 5000 ); 
   function updateContent() 
    { 
         $('#feed').empty(); 
         $('#feed').load("load.php"); 
    } 
</script> 
<div id="feed">
</div>
```

load.php

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "n/a";
$dbname = "n/a";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


  session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["user"]) or !is_array($_SESSION["user"]) or empty($_SESSION["user"])
)

      // redirect to index page if not superuser
header('Location: index.php');

                $now = time(); $utc_time = $now - intval(date('Z', $now)); 

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT users.id, users.firstname, users.lastname, 
    feed.date, feed.time, feed.text, feed.userID, feed.ip, feed.post_id, feed.format, feed.file_format, feed.MediaTxt, feed.author_firstname, feed.author_lastname, feed.shared
FROM users 
JOIN friends
    ON users.id IN (friends.sender, friends.recipient)
JOIN feed 
    ON (users.id = feed.userID)
WHERE ".$_SESSION["user"]["id"]." IN (friends.sender,friends.recipient) 
    AND friends.status = 1
ORDER BY feed.date DESC, feed.time DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<div class='feed'><div class='feedtext'><h4 class='feedfontname'>" 
         . $row["firstname"]. 
         " "
          . $row["lastname"]. 
          "</h4><h4 style='color:gray'>"
          . $row["shared"]. " "
          . $row["author_firstname"]. " "
          . $row["author_lastname"]. "</h4><h6 class='feedfontstyle'>"
          . $row["MediaTxt"]. "</h6><"
          . $row["format"]." class='feedfontstyle' src='http://www.socialnetwk.com/users/". $_SESSION["user"]["id"] ."/feed/"
          . $row["format"]."/". $row["post_id"]."."
          . $row['file_format']."' ". $row['format'] . ">". $row['text'] ."</". $row['format'] ."></div><h6 class='feedtimefont'>". $row['time']."</h6>";




    }
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Since neither server nor PHP code is clairvoyant, you should send to server timestamp of last got message, or ID of it, or something like this. And then you will be able to select only newer messages on server.

Comment: Right, do you know any tutorial I could follow for this? I'm moving into Ajax area / Php area after I already know HTML,CSS,SQL. And the server timestamp is the time of the server correct?

Comment: @CassieJRound well, _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_. What you can do is to save ID or timestamp on client using JavaScript and pass it as parameter to `"load.php?last=" + last`

Comment: Well, it's fine now. I've already changed the DB pass